# Probar funciones de Bootstrap con Jest

Tags: bootstrap, jestjs

He intentado testear con Jest unas funciones Javascript en las que hago llamadas a funciones propias del framework de Bootstrap. El problema está en que no reconoce las funciones, por lo que sospecho que debo añadir algún tipo de referencia al código del framework de Bootstrap dentro de mi fichero de pruebas o en el archivo package.json.

Aquí les pongo un ejemplo de lo que me está sucediendo:

```
TypeError: $(...).collapse is not a function

  569 |
  570 | function showItemTwo() {
> 571 |     $("#collapseTwo").collapse('show');
      |                       ^
  572 |     $("#ItemTwoBtn").prop("disabled", false);
  573 |     $("#ItemThreeBtn").prop("disabled", true);
  574 | }

  at Object.collapse [as showItemTwo] (../Scripts/file1.js:571:23)
  at Object.showItemTwo (file1.test.js:10:20)
```

Este sería mi fichero de pruebas

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('../Scripts/jquery');
import ('../Scripts/bootstrap.min'); //¿?
const file1= require('../Scripts/file1');

describe('Comprobaciones de acciones de stepper', function () {
    test('Test1', () => {
        file1.showItemTwo();
        expect($("#ItemThreeBtn").attr("disabled").toBeTruthly());
    });
});
```

Solución: Finalmente lo que he hecho es agregar vía npm los paquetes de bootstrap, jquery y popper en sus últimas versiones: `npm install bootstrap --save` y así con el resto de paquetes

El fichero de pruebas finalmente queda así:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
require('bootstrap');
require('popper');
const file1= require('../Scripts/file1');

describe('Comprobaciones de acciones de stepper', function () {
    test('Test1', () => {
        file1.showItemTwo();
        expect($("#ItemThreeBtn").attr("disabled").toBeTruthly());
    });
});
```